# Android service timer crash

Tags: java, android, database, service, timer

I'm developing an app. In it user can input his friend's information - name and date of birth. When information is added, a service should start which should count how much time left and send a notification, when friend is having a birthday soon. Service takes info from database. When I add information, service just crashes. Here's my service code

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
DB2 db;
Cursor cursor;
Calendar x = Calendar.getInstance();
int y = x.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m = x.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int d = x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int h = x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min = x.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int s = x.get(Calendar.SECOND);
Handler handler;
NotificationManager nm;
int l, p, a, i, month, hours, minutes, seconds, m22, d22, v, g, t;
int[] k = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run(){
        MS2.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                db.open();
                cursor = db.getAllData();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int d110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day")); //here it should do some manipulations with every item in DB.

                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());//takes next item

                }
            }
        });
        cursor.close();
    }
}
private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
    handler.post(runnable);
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //db = new DB2(this);
    //db.open();
}





public void not() {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TEST2.class);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = new DB2(this);
    db.open();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Running ", 1).show();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1000);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

When I have my code like this

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run(){
                db.open();
                cursor = db.getAllData();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int d110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day")); //here it should do some manipulations with every item in DB.

                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());//takes next item

                }

        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

There's no crash. Just no notification

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to Stackoverflow. For this kind of question, it would generally be helpful if you could post a Stacktrace of the crash, as that may give a good indication of where the problem lies.

Comment: There's no crash log

Comment: No stacktrace whatsoever? That seems weird. Can you elaborate on when and how exactly the service crashes?

Comment: From what I've seen I can say next: when I add info, it runs through my code once. (If I input today's date, it sends a notification once. I forgot to mention that user can input hour and minute of birthday). If I input at least 1 minute more, it runs through my code, and service just crashes. Minute later no notification

Comment: It's probably has to do something with cursor. Same code (without cursors) works in another service with single person, using SharedPreferences

Comment: This is what I get, but only when I close emulator: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.database.Cursor.close()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.dc2.MS2$UpdateTimeTask.run(MS2.java:286)
            at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Comment: I think the NPE comes because your cursor.close is outside the RunOnUiThread-Call, while the Cursor is inside. Otherwise, I'm sorry to say that I don't quite understand your code right now, so I'm having trouble finding out what is going wrong. Are you sure your code is not just finished iterating and stops? Have you tried adding some Logging to better understand what is going on (`Log.d()` is your friend)?

Comment: It almost worked for me, after I've replaced cursor.close inside the RunOnUiThread. The only problem that is left - timer only works once for me. If I input current time, it sends me notification without any crashes. But when I input like 1 minute more, it doesn't send me anything. I've set timer to update every 30 seconds, but it doesn't happen.